# BroadcastReceiver is not called from service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, pubnub

I am starting a service from fragment and passing some data to it and from service I am calling the PubNub for notification then after showing the notification I am sending the sendbroadcast but while sending the broadcast it is not getting receive in activity page.

Activity

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("sample-event")) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.d("Pubnub Message", "Got message: " + message);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction("sample-event");
    this.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, filter);
}
```

Fragment

```
Intent pubBunintent = new Intent(mContext,Pubnub.class);
pubBunintent.putExtra("AuthKeyArray",AuthkeyArray);
pubBunintent.putExtra("channelKeyArray",ChannelArray);
mContext.startService(pubBunintent);
```

Service

```
public class Pubnub extends Service {

    private ArrayList<String> Auth;
    private ArrayList<String> Channel;
    private String PubNubSubscribeKey = "key";
    private String PubNubPublishKey = "key";
    private Context mContext = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        StartPubnub();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Auth = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("AuthKeyArray");
        Channel = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("channelKeyArray");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void StartPubnub() {
        PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
        pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey(PubNubSubscribeKey);
        pnConfiguration.setPublishKey(PubNubPublishKey);
        pnConfiguration.setSecure(true);
        pnConfiguration.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        pnConfiguration.setAuthKey(Auth.get(0));
        PubNub pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);

        // Grant PAM Permissions for channel and auth_key, User Level Grant
        pubnub.grant()
                .channels(Channel)
                .authKeys(Auth) // the keys we are provisioning
                .write(true) // allow those keys to write (false by default)
                .read(true) // allow keys to read the subscribe feed (false by default)
                .ttl(0)// how long those keys will remain valid (0 for eternity)
                .async(new PNCallback<PNAccessManagerGrantResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(PNAccessManagerGrantResult result, PNStatus status) {
                        // PNAccessManagerGrantResult is a parsed and abstracted response from server
                        Log.d("pubnub", "onResponse: grant " + status.toString());
                    }
                });

        pubnub.addListener(new SubscribeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
                if (status.getOperation() != null) {
                    switch (status.getOperation()) {
                        case PNSubscribeOperation:
                        case PNUnsubscribeOperation:
                            switch (status.getCategory()) {
                                case PNConnectedCategory:
                                    Log.d("pubnub", "onResponse: connected ");
                                case PNReconnectedCategory:
                                    Log.d("pubnub", "onResponse: reconnected ");
                                    break;
                                case PNDisconnectedCategory:
                                case PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory:
                                    pubnub.reconnect();
                                    break;
                                case PNAccessDeniedCategory:
                                case PNBadRequestCategory:
                                    Log.d("pubnub", "onResponse: bad ");
                                    pubnub.reconnect();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Log.d("pubnub", "onResponse: bad ");
                                    pubnub.reconnect();
                            }
                        case PNHeartbeatOperation:
                            if (status.isError()) {
                            } else {
                            }
                            break;
                        default: {
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    status.getCategory();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
                if (message.getChannel() != null) {
                    Log.d("Pubnub", "message: " + message.toString() + "Channel" + message.getChannel());
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                    JsonElement pushMessage;
                    jsonObject = message.getMessage().getAsJsonObject();
                    pushMessage = jsonObject.get("message");
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
                    builder.setContentTitle("Sample")
                            .setContentText(pushMessage.toString())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
                    Constant.PushnoteReceived = true;

                    Intent intent = new Intent("sample-event");
                    intent.putExtra("message", pushMessage.toString());
                    //Put your all data using put extra
                    sendBroadcast(intent);

                } else {
                    Log.d("Pubnub", "message complete: " + message.toString() + "Subscription" + message.getSubscription());
                    Log.d("Pubnub", "message: " + message.getMessage());
                    Log.d("Pubnub", "Time token: " + message.getTimetoken());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {
            }
        });

        //subscribe
        pubnub.subscribe().channels(Channel).execute();
        //  Adding Device to Channel: Enable push notifications on provided set of channels.
        pubnub.addPushNotificationsOnChannels()
                .pushType(PNPushType.GCM)
                .channels(Channel)
                .deviceId("com.sample.deviceTokenKey")
                .async(new PNCallback<PNPushAddChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(PNPushAddChannelResult result, PNStatus status) {
                        // handle response.
                        if (status.isError()) {
                            Log.d("pubnub", "onResponse: push note ERROR");
                            Log.d("pubnub", "onResponse: push " + status.toString());
                        } else {
                            Log.d("pubnub", "onResponse: push " + status.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you unregister your receiver? Is your `Activity` is in the foreground while the `Service` is running?

Comment: @earthw0rmjim yes onStop i am doing unregister

Comment: @earthw0rmjim yes m activity is in foreground while service is running